# How to iterate through data column by column and feed them to a three.js 3D model?

Tags: javascript, html, excel, three.js

I am developing a 3D model using three.js which show the position and orientation of a vehicle using accelerometer and gyroscope.
I have an xlsx file containing the data for x, y, z, roll, yaw and pitch. So far I have the 3D model running on a randomly generated data, on the other hand, I developed the code that read the xlsx file and display the data.

My plan is, after reading the xlsx file, I iterate through the x column, y column etc. and use them inside the 3D model code (replacing the random generated data by the real data).

My xlsx data format are like below:

[image]

and here is the file:

[Click here to download the data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/11ww2Knot5eppUKVhRbOdktO0zpdV-3G9/view?usp=sharing)

This is my code to read from the xlsx file:

```
var parser = new (require('simple-excel-to-json').XlsParser)();
var doc = parser.parseXls2Json('data/TestingWithThresholdXLSX.xlsx');
// convert json to string
var docToString = JSON.stringify(doc)
// parsing the JSON string text into a javascript Object
var json = JSON.parse(docToString);
// Loop through the json string
var text;
for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    text = json[0][i]["TimeId"];
    console.log(text)
  }
```

and this is my code for making the 3D model:

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="css" href="css/style.css">
   <script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.min.js"></script>
   <script src= "https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"> </script>
   <script src="https://requirejs.org/docs/release/2.3.6/comments/require.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script type="module"> import * as THREE from "https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/resources/threejs/r122/build/three.module.js"</script>
  </head>

<h1 style="color:red">3D Model Rotation and Translation</h1>
<body>
 <canvas id="canvas" width="1500" height="800" style="border:1px solid #000000;"></canvas>
 <div id="accelPanel"></div>
</body>
<script src="js/index.js"></script>
</html>
```

**Javascript**

```
function main() {
  const canvas = document.querySelector('#canvas');
  const accelPanel = document.querySelector('#accelPanel');
  const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({canvas});
  var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
  
  const fov = 60;
  const aspect = 2;  // the canvas default
  const near = 0.1;
  const far = 2000;
  const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(fov, aspect, near, far);
  camera.position.set(0, 50, 1.5);
  camera.up.set(0, 0, 1);
  camera.lookAt(0, 0, 0);
  
  const scene = new THREE.Scene();
  {
    const color = 0xFFFFFF;
    const intensity = 1;
    const light = new THREE.PointLight(color, intensity);
    scene.add(light);
  }
  // an array of objects who's rotation to update
  const objects = [];
  const radius = 3;
  const widthSegments = 3;
  const heightSegments = 3;
  const sphereGeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(radius, widthSegments, heightSegments);
  const sunMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: "green",wireframe: false}); 
  const sunMesh = new THREE.Mesh(sphereGeometry, sunMaterial);

  var cubeAxis = new THREE.AxesHelper(10);
    sunMesh.add(cubeAxis);

  sunMesh.scale.set(2, 2, 2);
  scene.add(sunMesh);
  objects.push(sunMesh);

  function resizeRendererToDisplaySize(renderer) {
    const canvas = renderer.domElement;
    const width = canvas.clientWidth;
    const height = canvas.clientHeight;
    const needResize = canvas.width !== width || canvas.height !== height;
    if (needResize) {
      renderer.setSize(width, height, false);
    }
    return needResize;
  }
  
  function render(speed) {
    speed *= 0.001;

    if (resizeRendererToDisplaySize(renderer)) {
      const canvas = renderer.domElement;
      camera.aspect = canvas.clientWidth / canvas.clientHeight;
      camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    }

    /* This is where I assume the data should be placed*/
    objects.forEach((obj) => {
      obj.rotation.x = speed+1;
      obj.rotation.y = speed+2;
      obj.rotation.z = speed+34;
      obj.position.x = speed+1;
      obj.position.y = speed+2;
      obj.position.z = speed+2;
      console.log(obj.position.y);
    });   
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}
main();
```

You can find the working code [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/samiarja/cezshq8f/2/)

I tried to play around and placing the data reader code inside the javascript code for 3D model, specifically after objects.forEach((obj) =>, but it never worked and I am a semi-beginner in javascript, so I appreciate any help to guide through this problem.

Comment: Are the data read in ok?

Comment: What do the values in your data represent exactly? Are gyro_xyz the euler angles for rotation in degrees? Why is there a accelero_magnitude, when accelero_xyz is not normalized?
For determining the position you would have to integrate over acceleration two times to get the position. This is totally possible, I just wonder how to interpret the values.

Comment: @atomh33ls yes it is working fine

Comment: @JosefWittmann yes, the gyro_xyz are the angles (roll, yaw and pitch), I should have named them better. The accelerometer magnitude will not be used, it is just there for additional information. The accelerometer XYZ are the row data coming from the sensor, I haven't done any normalization or pre-processing on it.

Comment: So accelero_xyz show the direction and magnitude of acceleration (I assume in m/s^2)?

Comment: And it would be great for reproduction, if you could upload the actual xlsx file (or share the values in a copy-friendly format)

Comment: @JosefWittmann yes exactly. I edited the question and added a link for the data file. Thanks for the remark

Comment: I also uploaded the code on jsfiddle, please find the link in the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The browser can't handle `.xlsx` files. Parse it to a JSON file (with node.js) beforehand.
   This script takes `data.xlsx` from the same directory and outputs it to `data.json` (you're free to make it more efficient in terms of file size).

```js
const fs = require('fs')
const path = require('path')
const { XlsParser } = require('simple-excel-to-json')

const SECONDS_PER_DAY = 24 * 60 * 60

const json = (new XlsParser()).parseXls2Json(path.resolve(__dirname, 'data.xlsx'));
const data = json[0].map((item) => ({
    time: item.TimeId * SECONDS_PER_DAY,
    rotX: deg2Rad(item.Gyro_X),
    rotY: deg2Rad(item.Gyro_Y),
    rotZ: deg2Rad(item.Gyro_Z),
    accX: item.Accelero_X,
    accY: item.Accelero_Y,
    accZ: item.Accelero_Z,
}))
fs.writeFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, 'data.json'), JSON.stringify(data))

function deg2Rad(angle) {
    return angle * Math.PI / 180
}
```

2. When rendering compute the current position by integrating acceleration.

```js
let currentIndex = 0
let time = data[currentIndex].time
let velocity = new THREE.Vector3()
requestAnimationFrame(render);

function render(dt) {
    dt *= 0.001 // in seconds
    time += dt
    document.querySelector("#time").textContent = time.toFixed(2)

    // Find datapoint matching current time
    while (data[currentIndex].time < time) {
        currentIndex++
        if (currentIndex >= data.length) return
    }
    const { rotX, rotY, rotZ, accX, accY, accZ } = data[currentIndex]
    const acceleration = new THREE.Vector3(accX, accY, accZ)
    object.rotation.set(rotX, rotY, rotZ)
    object.position.add(velocity.clone().multiplyScalar(dt)).add(acceleration.clone().multiplyScalar(0.5 * dt ** 2))
    velocity.add(acceleration.clone().multiplyScalar(dt))

    resizeToClient();
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
}
```

You can find everything in a GitHub repo I created:
https://github.com/Josef37/threejs-from-xlsx